# Symbol similar to thermistor

Tags: schematics

Ive come across this

[image: pinout diagram]
<sub>(source: [rapidonline.com](http://www.rapidonline.com/catalogueimages/module/M029525L01WD.gif))</sub>

its a 4PDT switch, Im not sure of the symbol or the purpose of pins 13 and 14

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the part? Is there an external latch/reset for it?

Comment: Is it possibly a relay and that extra block is the coil?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I think you have have it. Though im not familiar with that being a coil.

Comment: From what I've found, the notation is pretty similar to a relay.This is true for some of the 4PDT relay datasheets you can find on RapidOnline's website. For example, http://www.rapidonline.com/pdf/60-1312.pdf

Comment: That certainly looks like a 4PDT relay to me - pins 13 and 14 are the relay coil.  Can you provide a part number, or a link to the product description?

Answer (score 1):

That image came from Rapid Online and while it's still available in the location you've linked to it's been removed from their [General Purpose Power Relays 7A 4PDT](http://www.rapidonline.com/Cables-Connectors/7A-Power-relay-4PDT-29525) page where it used to be. So it looks like the symbol they've used for a regular 4PDT power relay.

You can view a version of the page as at March 2, 2013 on [The Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130302075312/http://www.rapidonline.com/Electronic-Components/General-Purpose-Power-Relays-7A-4PDT-29525) that includes the image.